# Using Container-fluid in Boostrap-React?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm attempting to use Container-fluid with Bootstrap-React and am having issues with importing.

I've tried importing container fluid, and also attempted to utilize the container API provided by bootstrap to generate the containerfluid, neither worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/), you should only import `Container`. If you want to make your `Container` as `fluid` then you can add `fluid` prop to `Container`.

```
import { Container } from `react-bootstrap`;
```

And usage

```
<Container fluid>
  ...
</Container>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it does not work. The code compiles successfully but the Container does not change to fluid.

Comment: Have you added `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: That worked. I found width constraints coded into the css sheet.